# Android kotlin import synthetic if else

Tags: android, kotlin

Is there any way to import a synthetic layout like:

If (App.layout1) import ...layout1 else layout2

?

I basically need this feature;)
Thanks

Comment: you can import both synthetic

Comment: The items name is the same in both layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you can rename imports in kotlin

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.activity1.someView as value1
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.activity2.someView as value2
```

But that might cause you to manually import all views manually. (Not tested) Maybe you can import the whole synthetic class instead of all views

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.activity1 as views1
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.activity2 as views2
```

And then

```
if (...) views1.someView.stuff() else views2.someView.stuff()
```

Conditional import is probably not supported because Java doesn't support it.

Comment: Very nice answer. Maybe the solution is val rootview=if (...) views1 else views2 then using just rootview or sg like that